# jquery, добавить класс по клику

Tags: jquery, css3

Добрый вечер. Ребят, помогите пожалуйста. Есть переключатель, по клику на него к определенной секции нужно добавить класс. Желательно сделать на jquery.

Первая строчка правильная, добавляю класс самому переключателю. А второй строчкой хочу добавить класс по клику на него, только не самому переключателю, а другому блоку. Спасибо

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
        $(this).toggleClass("bgc")
    });

});
```

Comment: замените `$(this)` в `$(this).toggleClass("bgc")` на селектор "другого блока"

Comment: Конкретнее укажите какой второй блок, а так правильно пишет Igor

Comment: Большое спасибо, все заработало )

Comment: @FghsdfsdfFghfghfdsf На здоровье. Успехов!